# Remove response array wrapper in spyne httprpc -> json

Tags: json, spyne

Out of the box Spyne seems to wrap an output JSON(P) message in an array. With

```
 out_protocol=JsonP('serviceResp', ignore_wrappers=True),
```

I get ~

```
    serviceResp([{ ... }]);
```

With

```
    out_protocol=JsonP('serviceResp', ignore_wrappers=False),
```

It wraps it in a Result/Response wrapper,

```
    serviceResp({"appResponse": {"appResult": [{ ... }]);
```

I've tried setting  _body_style='bare', to see if it had any effect but get an error regarding too many function params (??).

```
     Exception: body_style='bare' can handle at most one function argument.
```

I've also tried setting the _returns= to various types with no luck.

EDIT1: Here is some sample code that does in fact wrap the result in an array.
EDIT2: Amended the code below to yield a simpler message.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
from spyne.application import Application
from spyne.decorator import srpc
from spyne.service import ServiceBase
from spyne.model.primitive import Integer
from spyne.model.primitive import Unicode
from spyne.model.complex import Iterable
from spyne.protocol.http import HttpRpc
from spyne.protocol.json import JsonDocument
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication

class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @srpc(_returns=Unicode)
    def say_hello():
        yield 'Hello, James'

application = Application([HelloWorldService],
    tns='spyne.examples.hello',
    in_protocol=HttpRpc(validator='soft'),
    out_protocol=JsonDocument()
)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # You can use any Wsgi server. Here, we chose
    # Python's built-in wsgi server but you're not
    # supposed to use it in production.
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8000, wsgi_app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

http://server/say_hello

```
["Hello, James"]
```

Can anyone explain how to remove the array wrapper from the response?

-James

Answer (score 0):

**Answer after the edit:** Your return type designation says `Unicode` but you are returning an array of `str` objects. Return a single `unicode` object and not an iterable of strings and you should be fine.

---

**1.**

Under the hood, every RPC has one argument -- the request object. In bare mode you get to produce this object manually.

So a non-bare method like this:

```
@rpc(Integer, Unicode, Unicode, DateTime)
def foo(ctx, i, s1, s2, d):
    pass
```

Becomes:

```
class FooRequest(ComplexModel):
    i = Integer
    s1 = Unicode
    s2 = Unicode
    d = DateTime        

@rpc(FooRequest, _body_style='bare')
def foo(ctx, req):
    pass
```

In wrapped mode, Spyne does this automatically for you. In bare mode, you are on your own.

**2.**

Spyne doesn't wrap responses in arrays. If you have a look at the [relevant test](https://github.com/plq/spyne/blob/1f732e4dac659cfdc59d80cb6724e1f5d61d684c/spyne/test/protocol/test_json.py#L177), you will see that the actual output is this:

```
some_callback({"i": 42, "s": "foo"});
```

I could perhaps help you more tracking down where that array is coming from but you seemingly are nothing more than an average empathically-challenged who ask *Spyne* questions without *Spyne* code, so you need to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Above is a MWE. It still wraps the reply in a [ ] and I am at a loss being an early learner at your framework.

Comment: Thanks for the review again Burak. I've amended the sample code from spyne.io to definitely not try to return array but it still does. :?

Comment: You are not returning, you are yielding. They are two very different things. Please try to return stuff and yield only when you are sure you need to.

Comment: A single yield of a str object means an iterable with a single element. So it's still an array from json's perspective.

Comment: Yep, that did it! I didn't even think to look at yield vs return. This is the accepted answer, thanks Burak!